# Find the volume of the solid using double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let E be the solid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which lies on xy-plane and between the following surfaces:

1. Planes given by $y=0$ and $y=3$
2. Planes given by $x=0$ and $x=5$
3. The graph of the function is $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}, f(x,y)=10-x*y$

I constructed the equation $ \int\limits_0^3  \int\limits_0^5  10-xy\  dx \ dy  $ and found $\frac {375}{4}$ for my answer but it is wrong. Can anyone provide some hints?

Comment: Please include your calculations in the question - then it will be easier to point out the possible error.

Comment: Try finding out what the intersection of the graph with the $ xy $ plane looks like. Is $ f $ always non-negative for $ x \in [0, 5] $, $ y \in [0, 3] $?

Comment: Good point:  the problem statement is a bit careless, but the poser may only be interested in the portion above the $ \ xy-$plane, in which case the hyperbola $ \ xy \ = \ 10 \ $ is another part of the boundary of the integration region.